# C++ enable_if_t SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to understand why this piece is code isn't working as expected

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

struct Foo {

};

template<typename T, typename = void>
void compare(const T&a, const T&b) {
    cout << "default" << endl;
}

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, Foo>::value>>
void compare(const T& a, const T &b) {
    cout << "In object" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    compare(1, 2);

    {
        vector<int> a, b;
        compare(a, b);
    }

    {
        Foo a, b;
        compare(a, b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In all cases "default" is printed. For the last case I would expect that the 2nd function to get invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specialize `compare` (it's impossible to partially specialize a function template anyway). Instead you provide an overload.

And the overload is always illegal:

1. Either `enable_if_t` is not defined.
2. Or it specifies a non-type template parameter of type `void`.

So it's never going to be called, because SFINAE discards it in favor of the always valid overload at the top.

Specialization is usually the wrong answer for function templates. Instead you should delegate to a class template, which *will* behave as expected upon true specialization:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct compare_impl { 
  static void execute(T const& l, T const& r) { /*Base case code*/ }
};

template<typename T>
struct compare_impl<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, Foo>::value>> {
   static void execute(T const& l, T const& r) { /*Special case code*/ }
};

template<typename T>
void compare (T const& l, T const& r) { compare_impl<T>::execute(a, b); }
```

Comment: Thanks ! I sort of understand now :) In the compare function we need to do compare_impl<T>:: instead, I guess

Comment: @jack_carver - Ack, I knew I'd miss something.

Comment: You also switch from parameters `(l, r)` to `(a, b)` in the `compare` function.

Answer (score 2):

Using a class template is a valid solution, here's another way to achieve this result with tag dispatching:

```
    template <class T>
    void compare(const T & l, const T & r, std::true_type)
    {
      cout << "In object" << endl;
    }

    template <class T>
    void compare(const T & l, const T & r, std::false_type)
    {
      cout << "default" << endl;
    }

    template <class T>
    void compare(const T & l, const T & r)
    {
      compare(l, r, std::is_same<T, Foo>{});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Deferring to a specialised function object allows a lot of flexibility on how argument types and/or whether they are rvalues or lvalues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;


// general case
template<class T> 
struct compare_impl
{
    template<class U, class V>
    auto operator()(U&& a, V&& b) const {
        cout << "default" << endl;
    }
};

// compare interface
template<class T, class U>
auto compare(T && a, U && b)
{
    using ctype = std::common_type_t<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<U>>;
    auto impl = compare_impl<ctype>();
    return impl(a, b);
}


// now specialise for objects for which we want custom behaviour
struct Foo {

};

template<>
struct compare_impl<Foo>
{
    template<class U, class V>
    auto operator()(U&& a, V&& b) const {
        cout << "In object" << endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    compare(1, 2);

    {
        vector<int> a, b;
        compare(a, b);
    }

    {
        Foo a, b;
        compare(a, b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```